# SSH into Virtual Machine thorugh another PC in the same network, Creating Bridge Network

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualization, network-bridge

I created a Virtual Machine using Virtual Machine Manager. I am using a Ubuntu OS(.iso) for the VM. After creating a VM it automatically assigns a IP to the VM. I can only SSH from the host Machine to the VM and it works (OpenSSH-server has been installed). But when I try to SSH into the VM from another machine it doesn't work it says

> Connection timed out

**What I have tried.**
I have tried creating a Virtual bridge network on the host machine through nmtui and also have specified it in the VMM settings for the VM. Same thing I can't SSH from another machine into the VM, I can do it through the Host VM.

I want to SSH into it through the other machine. How can I achive this?

Comment: in vbox settings then network, switch to "bridged adapter" then save and reboot vm

Comment: If you are using VirtualBox, then set the network’s “Promiscuous Mode” to “Allow All”. This is found under the Advanced options for the network adapter.

Comment: @petep I have switch to "bridge adapter" and also rebooted the system. But that too doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's unclear if the VM Host and the SSH Client are on the same network, or if they are across at least one router.

Comment: @user535733 They are in the same network.

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1489542/edit) instead to add new information and clarifications.

Comment: "*I can only SSH from the host Machine to the VM and it works*" demonstrates that there is nothing wrong with your Ubuntu system. This is a how-do-I-use-Virtualbox question. "*I have tried creating a Virtual bridge network on the host machine through nmtui and also have specified it in the VMM settings for the VM*" is on the right track: Review the Virtualbox manual for setting up a Bridged network. You want the VM Guest to get the IP address from your router, and that is indeed a Bridged network. Then both will REALLY be on the same network, and SSH across the LAN will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best way but it is one way to solve the problem:

Assuming that you can SSH into the host machine (if not then you probably need to install OpenSSH-server on the host) try this:

```
ssh -C -J username@hostmachine vm_username@vm_address
```

The -C is optional, allows compression of the data

Replace username and hostmachine with the username you use on the VM host and the address of the VM host

Replace the vm_username and vm_address, the latter with the local address you'd use when doing an ssh session from the host.

If it doesn't work there may be a config option you need to change in the ssh configuration on the host machine to allow this to work, search on "jump server" or "bastion server" for more information.

This page might provide more help:

[How to use SSH command and config with a jump (bastion) host and save a lot of time](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1303/small-ssh-config-time-saver-jump-bastion-host)